# How can I change the dropdown option into different form on product page?

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I am a newbie in Magento and i got something very tricky on product page. I have to hide the drop-down option from here and show all the attributes values in a single line like

[Size : Small Medium Large]

[Color : Red Green Pink]

but the color will only show after selecting the size like in default Magento drop-down. I am able to get all the attribute according to the product id but how can i get the color attribute according to the size attribute for a particular product, and then pass that values to the cart page after clicking on the add to cart button.

I have really stuck in this task can someone help me please..

Comment: If I understand you correct, Marius built an extension to solve this issue: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Comment: Thanks for your reply and you understand me correctly,but this extension is not doing anything, neither in backend nor in frontend.

Comment: I'm sure this extension works. Didn't tried it but I can't imagine Marius is faking the work of a whole extension ;-) Supposing this, you forgot to clear the cache or something else.

Comment: ok.. let me try one more time. hope this will work..

Comment: @waseem. Read the documentation first. https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use. It states in there that the extension behavior is disabled after installation. You have to enable it manually.

Comment: @Marius I have used it perfectly, Thanks for such amazing extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so this question can have an answer....
I recommend [this extension](http://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher) (the OP already confirmed that is using it). It can change your dropdowns to labels with the option texts, or even with the simple product images. It can do even more than that. Full description provided [here](http://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Hey Marius, it's in Beta. can it still be used on production shops? Cause this extension is awesome and love to work with it on some projects

Comment: @SanderMangel. It is in beta, because it was the first release and I wanted to get some opinions from the community. it's hard to fully test my own code. It seams to work fine. I got only one complaint for not working with a very custom theme and conflicting with a very custom image zoomer. So I guess it doesn't work for everyone, but with some developer skills it can be done. If you test it out and find issues or have ideas on how to make it better please shout.

Comment: Perfect, I'll fork it if I have a solution and otherwise I'll just shoot a ticket your way. Thanks!

Comment: @SanderMangel. If you plan to use the extension get the new version. Just fixed a small bug this morning.

Comment: Great, I think we'll use it for the next project that starts in 2 weeks. But before that I will install it in a test store and discus it internally with the developers and frontenders what to touch and not to touch ;)